# Executing unit test cases through ant in the process of creating build

Tags: java, ant, junit

I am executing ant build, can we automate unit test cases along with the build creation.

Comment: Yes. (Not what you wanted to hear? Odd...)

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688747/how-do-i-run-junit-tests-during-my-ant-build-script-while-omitting-test-classes

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a JUnit task in your ant script.

```
   <junit>
     <test name="my.test.TestCase"/>
   </junit>
```

See [JUnit Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) for documentation.