# Ant build of maven spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, maven, ant, spring-boot

Is there any way to compile, build, run test and create runnable jar with Ant if the dependency is managed through Maven?

The case is that server has only Ant.

Script like this one: 
[How do I run JUnit tests during my Ant build script while omitting test classes from my resulting jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688747/how-do-i-run-junit-tests-during-my-ant-build-script-while-omitting-test-classes) in the accepted answer.

How to specify where are the libraries located?

Comment: Have you looked into Apache Ivy?

Comment: I think the best guess is to avoid ant, and maybe just add maven to the server. Maven is not really needed to be installed through the linux distribution. It is a just a zip file which you extract.

Answer (score 1):

Some docs here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-build-an-executable-archive-with-ant. The sample build config from there:

```
<target name="build" depends="compile">
    <copy todir="target/classes/lib">
        <fileset dir="lib/runtime" />
    </copy>
    <jar destfile="target/spring-boot-sample-actuator-${spring-boot.version}.jar" compress="false">
        <fileset dir="target/classes" />
        <fileset dir="src/main/resources" />
        <zipfileset src="lib/loader/spring-boot-loader-jar-${spring-boot.version}.jar" />
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher" />
            <attribute name="Start-Class" value="${start-class}" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```